# React Native: panresponder native event identifier undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I have a view

```
<View style={styles.container} id={'time2'}>
  <Text>hello</Text>
</View>
```

and onComponentWillMount, I have a pan handler (inside PanResponder.create)

```
onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
  console.log('identifier', evt.identifier);
}
```

but when I press the view, the identifier gets printed out as undefined.  Target is also undefined.  How do I get the id of my view to print out?

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the identifier from the nativeEvent property of the evt:

```
onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
   console.log('identifier', evt.nativeEvent.identifier);
}
```